# Show PDO Fecth All Colum in Custom Format

Tags: php, pdo

I have a PDO fecth function, the code is

```
function getAllUserTicketHistoryJson($rid){
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, total_ticket FROM ticket_user WHERE round_id = :rou");
    $stmt->bindParam(':rou', $rid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $res;
}
```

and call it in my index with this code

```
$getAllUserTicketHistoryJson = getAllUserTicketHistoryJson($getTicket['id']);
```

The output show like this

> Notice: Array to string conversion in...

what I want is to show all the fetch column like this one.

```
$array=array('key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value);
```

anyone can help me?

## EDIT

Why I want to format like this code

```
$array=array('user_id' => total_ticket, 'user_id' => total_ticket, 'user_id' => total_ticket, 'user_id' => total_ticket);
```

because I want to use it like this

```
$array=array('2' => 75.76, '3' => 15.15, '4' => 7.58, '1' => 1.52);
```

it will use in my next code

```
$number=rand(0,array_sum($array));
$starter=0;
foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
    $starter+=$val;
    if($number<=$starter)
    {
            $ret=$key;
            break;
    }

}

echo 'Winner is '.$ret.'<br/>';
```

Comment: Please show us what line the error occurs in. As far as I can see, there's nothing obvious in the posted code. _Side note:_ the name `$getAllUserTicketHistoryJson` is a bit strange since it returns an array, not json.

Comment: line 57 which is echo $getAllUserTicketHistoryJson; , what I want is to show all the data to this format $array=array('key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value);

Comment: do you want to show a json string equivalent of that array? Then you need to json_encode it first.

Comment: The function returns an array, which you're trying to echo straight off. You can't echo arrays. If you just want to output/debug the data, then you need to use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`. If you want to echo it as json, you need to use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert the array to a json string.

Comment: I already did this return json_encode($res); but the data show like this [{"user_id":"1","total_ticket":"1"},{"user_id":"2","total_ticket":"50"},{"user_id":"3","total_ticket":"10"},{"user_id":"4","total_ticket":"5"}] what I want is like show like this $array=array('key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value);

Comment: `$array=array('key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value);` is not json. What you got from `json_encode()` is. Your question is very unclear. Why would you want to output it like PHP code? And how is that related to json?

Comment: _"what I want is like show like this:.."_ - then don't json_encode but use `var_export($res, true)` ([The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)). But I highly doubt you really need/want this format. What for?

Comment: In your title you say _"in Json Format"_ - but you don't want json format, that's confusing..

Comment: this code $array=array('key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value); not in json format? so how to show into that format?

Comment: No, this `array('key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value, 'key' => value)` is not json. It's the result of a `var_export`. This `[{"user_id":"1","total_ticket":"1"},...` is [JSON](https://www.json.org/).

Comment: _"so how to show into that format?"_ - Which format are you talking about now? We've told you how to show it in json (json_encode()) and how to show it in PHP-format (var_export()). However, this makes no sense. Why do you want to output the data like that? What is it for? Please explain the flow and we might be able to give you some examples/pointers.

Comment: I updated the first post, please help

Comment: _after your update/edit_: it seems like you just want to use that array as array. So the answer would be to just do nothing with $res, but return it (as you do). It's an array allready, and you can use it in your foreach as it is. You don't need any "format".

Comment: How to format like what i want? I try this code , $data=array(); foreach($res as $key => $val){$data[] = '"'.$res['user_id'].'"'=>' .$key['total_ticket'].'';} and call it in index like $array=array($data); it not showing the array

Comment: there are so many basic php things that are wrong here that I can only recommend visiting some basic tutorials. Let alone the usage of $ret insife the foreach, the tried assignement to $data[], etc. read about arrays in general. Then about foreach. then functions and their return.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns an array, echo will output a string but cannot be used for arrays.

As you're trying to return results in Json format you should json encode your response when returning

```
function getAllUserTicketHistoryJson($rid){
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, total_ticket FROM ticket_user WHERE round_id = :rou");
    $stmt->bindParam(':rou', $rid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return json_encode($res);
}
```

json_encode() will return a json string instead of an array, so you'll be able to echo this.

If you're looking to output the contents of an array (instead of a json string), you should use var_dump() to do this.